# Calculate all extremums and decide whether there are global ones: $f(x)=x^{2} \cdot e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives, curves

> Calculate all extremums and decide whether they are global or not:
>   $f(x)=x^{2} \cdot e^{-x}$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I have of course started with derivatives (I have checked and they are correct!):

$$f'(x) = e^{-x}(2x-x^{2})$$

$$f''(x) = e^{-x}(x^{2}-4x+2)$$

$f'(x)=0$

$0=e^{-x}(2x-x^{2})$

$0=2x-x^{2}$

$0=x(2-x)$

$x_{1}=0$ $,$ $f''(0)=2$  $\Rightarrow$ minimum at $P(0|0)$

$x_{2}=2$ $,$ $f''(2)=-0,27$ $\Rightarrow$ maximum $Q(2|\frac{4}{e^{2}})$

So now comes the exciting part for me (I believe till here it is correct):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{2} \cdot e^{-x}= 0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}x^{2} \cdot e^{-x}= \infty$$

From this I can see that the minimum we calculated must be global minimum.

The maximum we calculated is local (so not global) because we are in $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and we know from above that there are greater maximums.

---

Please tell me if I did it right, I need to do that in the exam and I would do it like here?

Comment: I believe that the correct plural for extremum is extrema (and maxima, and minima, but maximums and minimums don't sound nearly as bad).

Comment: Anyway, your solution look correct to me.

Comment: There are no "greater maximums" (you exhibited the only local maximum), but there are points where that local maximum is exceeded. For globaliy of th eminimum, I'd simply state that for $x\ne 0$, both $x^2$ and $e^{-x}$ are positive.

Comment: Very very glad to hear this! Now I'm allowed to go sleep hehe :-)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud You're right, plural form for extremum is extrema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You can also note that $f(x)\ge 0 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, so $f(0)=0$ is a global minimum.